# Dapper.Contrib Support for composite primary key

Tags: dapper-contrib

Hy people, I have a short question to ask: 
    is there any support for composite primary keys in Dapper.Contrib, 
    and if not, dose anyone have an implementation i can use?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i did a bit of searching and came to the conclusion that DapperExtensions is more suited to my project needs as it supports composite primary keys via fluent mapping, while Contrib uses attributes. off course, it dose state here that Contrib dose not support composites, but I was still wondering if someone may have implemented it. In any case, DapperExtensions better fits my use case.